# lftp: how to recursively set permissions; firstly by directory than by file

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, shared-hosting, batch-processing, lftp

When securing a Drupal or WordPress installation on a shared host that does not expose SSH access (a lousy situation, fwiw) lftp seems like the right approach to batch setting permissions for directories and files. The find command boasts that you can redirect its output, so one should be able to run a find, grep exclude to only match lines ending in "/" meaning a directory, and then set the permissions on such matches to 755 and perform the inverse on file matches and set to 644 and then fine tune specific files, such as settings.php and so forth.

```
lftp prompt> find . | grep "/$" | xargs chmod -v 755
```

Isn't working and I'm sure I have failed to chain these commands in the correct sequence and format.

How to get this to work?

**Update:** by "isn't working" I mean that the above command produces no output to the console, nor to the lftp error log. It *isn't* running these commands locally, fwiw. I'll reduce the command as a demonstration:

```
find . | grep "/$"
```

Will take the output of "find" and return matches, here, directories, by nature of the string match:

```
./daily/
./ffmpeg-installer/
./hourly/
./includes/
./includes/database/
./includes/database/mysql/
./and_so_forth_on_down
```

Which is cool, since I wish to perform a chmod (and internal command for lftp, with support varying by ftp server) So I expand the command like this:

```
find . | grep "/$" | xargs echo
```

Which outputs — nothing. No error output, either. The pipe from grep to xargs isn't happening.

My goal is to form the equivalent of:

```
chmod 755 ./daily/
chmod 755 ./ffmpeg-installer/
```

In lftp, the chmod command is performing an ftp-server-permissions change, *not* a local perms change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an explanation of why this does not work as expected, read on - for a solution to the given problem, scroll down.

The answer can be found in the manpage for `lftp`, which states that

*"[s]ome commands allow redirecting their output (cat, ls, ...) to file or via pipe to external command."*

So, when you are using a pipe like this on a command that does support redirection in `lftp`, you are piping its output to your *local* tools, which will eventually result in `chmod` trying to change the permissions for a file/directory on our *local* machine, and most likely fail in case you don't coincidally have the same directory layout in your current directory locally - which is probably the problem you encountered.

The `grep` + `xargs` pipe does work, I just tested the following:

```
lftp> find -d 2 | grep "/$"
./
./applications/
./lost+found/
./netinfo/
./packages/
./security/
./systems/
lftp> find -d 2 | grep "/$" | xargs echo
./ ./applications/ ./lost+found/ ./netinfo/ ./packages/ ./security/ ./systems/
```

My wild guess is that it did not appear to work for you because you did not specify a max-depth to find and the network connection + buffering in the pipe got in the way. When I try the same on a directory containing many files/subfolders it takes really long to finish and print. Did the command actually finish for you without output?

But still, what you are trying to do is not possible. As I stated, the *right-hand-side* of the pipe works with *external* commands (even if an inbuilt of the same name exists) as explained by the manual, so

```
lftp> chmod 644 foobar
```

and

```
lftp> echo "foobar" | xargs chmod 644
```

are **not** equivalent.
Yes, `chmod` is an inbuilt but used in a pipe in the client it will **not** execute the inbuilt - the manpage clearly states this and you can easily test this yourself. Try the following commands and check their output:

```
lftp> echo foo | uname -a
lftp> echo foo | ls -al
lftp> echo foo | chmod --help
lftp> chmod --help
```

### Solution

As far as a solution to your problem is concerned, you can try something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

server="ftp.foo.bar"
root_folder="/my/path"

{
        {
                lftp "${server}" <<EOF
                cd "${root_folder}"
                find | grep "/$"
                quit
EOF
        } | awk '{ printf "chmod 755 \"%s\"\n", $0 }'

        {
                lftp "${server}" <<EOF
                cd "${root_folder}"
                find | grep -v "/$"
                quit
EOF
        } | awk '{ printf "chmod 644 \"%s\"\n", $0 }'
} | lftp "${server}"
```

This logs in to your server, `cd`s to the folder where you want to recursively start changing the permissions, uses `find + grep` to find all directories, logs out, pipes this file list into `awk` to build `chmod` commands around it, repeats the whole process for files and then pipes the whole list of commands into a new `lftp` invocation to actually run the generated `chmod` commands.

You will also have to add your credentials to the `lftp` invocations and you might want to comment out the final `| lftp "${server}"` to check if it produces the desired output before you actually run the whole thing. Please report back if this works for you!

Comment: No, the lftp man page quote is an explanation, but not an answer. The question remains unanswered. The behavior of the command I wrote doesn't conform with your guess, fwiw. There's no error output, either. So perhaps providing some granularity might help? I'll updated my main question accordingly.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for your update! No, your understanding of what is happening is incorrect (as per the manpage quote) and I updated my answer to demonstrate why.

Comment: Thanks [Adrian](http://stackoverflow.com/users/612462/adrian-fruhwirth) for the update. I'm seeing the disconnect in my approach, much thanks. But I'm hoping that in a macro sense what I'd like to do remains feasible, even if my poor attempt at it is fatally flawed.

Comment: @Kyle Well, it's not possible to do it in one shot as you attempted, but it can be scripted using your initial find/grep pipe as basis, see my updated answer.

Comment: This is excellent. I don't currently have a site that I can test this on in full, but based on my preflight examination, (as per your suggestion) this is perfect for what I'm looking for. I'll still beg my clients to allow ssh connections, and use this for the recalcitrant ones. A few comments: lftp lets you define bookmarks, which act like an alias. So, in preparation, you can define the alias for the server in question, and then pass that into the $server shell variable. When time allows, I'll expand this so I can pass this as arg into the script. Nice touch on setting the files to 644, btw.

Comment: @Kyle Perfect! Good tip on the bookmarking feature, and check back in case this gives you any headache later since I only gave it a quick test myself :-)